# Validating phone number with different formats WITHOUT regex

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript, I need validate phone numbers without using regular expressions (must be with string manipulation). The phone numbers have to be in one of the following formats:

1. 123-456-7890
2. 1234567890
3. (123)4567890
4. (123)456-7890

Then I must also provide an alert if the phone number isn't in one of the formats listed above.

I have only been able to manage to get #2 working, which looks something like this:

```
function len(gth) 
{
if (gth.value.length != 10) 
    {
        alert("Telephone numbers MUST be 10 digits!");
    }
}
```

which down in the HTML it would call up to the function:

```
<p>Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp; <input id = "phone" onblur="len(this)" name = "Phone" size = "20" type = "text" maxlength = "10"> </p>
```

Comment: if you can't use regex, cause it's too complicated, try regulazy http://osherove.com/blog/2006/7/9/introducing-regulazy-point-click-regular-expression.html it wiil create regex expression for you

Comment: You probably want a state machine looking at it char-by-char -- what are the valid chars in this state and what state does that move us to.  Note your current code would accept "abcdefghij" as a valid phone#

Comment: There is endless of possibilities to how you can write a phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a solution without regex, I believe this should work.

```js
const phones = [
  '123-456-7890',
  '1234567890',
  '(123)4567890',
  '(123)456-7890',
  '+61(123) 456-7890',
  '12345',
  '))))01/34$89.77(99'
]

function len(gth) {
    if (gth.substring(3, 4) == '-' && gth.substring(7, 8) == '-') // 123-456-7890
        gth = gth.replace('-', '').replace('-', '');
    else if (gth.substring(0, 1) == '(' && gth.substring(4, 5) == ')' && gth.substring(8, 9) == '-') // (123)456-7890
        gth = gth.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('-', '');
    else if (gth.substring(0, 1) == '(' && gth.substring(4, 5) == ')') // (123)4567890
        gth = gth.replace('(', '').replace(')', '');        
    
    if (!isNaN(gth) && gth.length == 10) {
        return true;
    }
    alert("Telephone numbers:" + gth + " MUST be 10 digits!");
}

phones.forEach(len)
```

Comment: This will pass "-123456789".

Comment: It's true @torazaburo would need some more `ifs`

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the numbers with something like `x`, then check against predefined patterns:

```
function check(num) {
  let pattern = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    pattern += num[i] >= '0' && num[i] <= '9' ? 'x' : num[i];
  }

  return ['xxx-xxx-xxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx', '(xxx)xxxxxxx', '(xxx)xxx-xxxx']
    .indexOf(pattern) >= 0;
}
```

For extra credit, find the bug in the above program.

However, you don't really need to do any of this. You should be able to use the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) attribute on the `input` element. That will also provide a better user experience. For instance, you can style the input element using the `:invalid` pseudo-class, by putting a red border around it for example, to give the user real-time feedback that their input is not valid. Yes, that takes a regular expression--what was your reason for not wanting to use a regular expression again?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it manually be:

- Checking string size if it is the expected or not
- split the string to char array then parse them as integers inside a try block if numberFormatException is thrown it should be a bracket  ( ) or -

Answer (score 0):

[Basic example](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/zoREoR) of extracting the input data to Array

```js
function test() {
  var phnTest = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  var strArray = [];
  strArray = phnTest.split('');
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = strArray;
}
```

```html
 <form action="demo_form.asp">
  Phone <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone"><br>
  <input type="button" value='Submit' onclick="test()">
</form> 
<p id='p'></p>
```

This is dependent on how the data is structured, if you need to search a body of text and so on, but basics would be...

If it's a simple pull from an `<input>`, grab the data...

Take the input data, and generate an array with each character. You could then test, say `strArray[3]`, for a dash or a dot. If not present, it can continue along to check for seven numbers in a row and so on.

This is going to be extremely consuming and require a number of conditionals to be checked. I assume the "without RegEx" is a requirement for a project or such, if not, recommend learning and using RegEx.

Hope this gets you going.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt. The key is creating an array from the string then filtering out any non numerical characters. It would be easier to use regular expression though. just

```
number.replace(/(\D+)/g, '')
```

```js
const numbers = [
  '123-456-7890',
  '1234567890',
  '(123)4567890',
  '(123)456-7890',
  '+61(123) 456-7890',
  '12345',
  '))))01/34$89.77(99'
]

// validate a phone number
function validate(number) {
  const digits = clean(number)
  console.log({
    number, 
    digits, 
    length: digits.length, 
    pass: digits.length === 10
  })
}

// remove any non digits from the number
function clean(number) {
  return Array.from(number).filter(char => {
    return !isNaN(char) && char !== ' '
  }).join('')
}

numbers.forEach(validate)
```

Comment: This will accept many string which are not phone numbers.  ))))01/34$89.77(99

Comment: @JohnHascall I don't follow your reasoning. The only requirement of the test is the length of the number. You cannot determine that with the junk characters that are not important to the phone in dialing. To actually validate it I would slice it for area codes and validate those individually.